# How to separate json data and file data in form-data in node.js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, multer, form-data, body-parser

I am trying to send files and json data in form-data from react.js to node.js. In the backend(node.js), I am unable to get the json data. I tried logging req.body and it logged-
`[Object: null prototype] {}`

ReactJS-

```
      const formData = new FormData();

      for (let i = 0; i < customOrderFiles.length; i++) {
        formData.append("files", customOrderFiles[i]);
      }

      console.log(formData.get("files"), formData.getAll("files"));

      Object.keys(customOrderDetails).forEach((key) => {
        formData.append(key, customOrderDetails[key]);
      });

      formData.append("userDetails", JSON.stringify(customOrderDetails));

      const res = await axiosInstance.post("/custom-order/create", formData);
      console.log("res.data", res.data);
```

Node.js-
I am using body-parser in index.js

```
app.use(cors()); 
app.use(express.static("Public")); 
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

customOrder.js

```
router.post(
  "/create",
  isSignedIn,
  upload.array("files", 25),
  handleMulterError,
  createCustomOrder
);
```

customOrderController.js

```
const createCustomOrder = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { fullName, phone, email, gender, quantity, description } = req.body;

    console.log(req.body, "req.body");

    const customOrder = await CustomOrder.create({
      user: req.user._id,
      fullName,
      phone,
      email,
      gender,
      quantity,
      description,
    });
    return res.status(200).json({ customOrder });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error");
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Something went wrong" });
  }
};
```